# Can I transfer a Windows installation from one disk to another by simple file copy?

Tags: windows, boot, bootloader, vhd

I have a virtual hard drive (.vhd file) with a Windows 8.1 installation, and a physical hard drive with data.
Can I transfer the 8.1 installation from one drive to the other without re-formatting anything?
I guess I would have to copy over all the folders, and then restore the boot sector?

**Why I want to do this:**

I want to upgrade from Windows 7 to 8.1, but have the option to go back if problems occur. All this without partitioning my hard drive.

1. Install Windows 8.1 onto a virtual hard drive (.vhd file)
2. Boot from the VHD, check it out, see if problems occur
3. Once everything works, delete Windows 7 from the hard drive, copy Windows 8.1 from the VHD onto the physical drive, delete the VHD. (And that's what I'm unclear about)

Comment: Note that filesystem permissions and any ADS data are lost when copying to a new partition. The Bootsec and MBR will have to be copied manually as you indicated.

Comment: Good point. Will Windows work, though? And do any Windows components rely on ADS? Also, I'd like to know if there is a simpler solution for what I want to do.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I have always recommended that people do NOT attempt to copy an OS like this, and instead look into imaging tools. In your case, I'd recommend you take a backup image of the existing OS before attempting your upgrade, and simply restore from it if the upgrade doesn't go well. There are some free tools here: http://lifehacker.com/5303067/five-best-free-system-restore-tools

Comment: Thank you! This looks to be the better solution indeed. Always dangerous to try something the system was not designed for.